# How to insert "US$" in R

Tags: r, datatable

I would like to insert `US$` before the numbers in my `datatable`. For example, US$ 4. How can I do this?

```
library(DT)


Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef1 = c(4, 1, 6, 1),coef2 = c(8, 3, 1, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Test<-Test%>%mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE))

z<-datatable (Test, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                   paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,dom = 'tip',scrollx=T),rownames = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `formatCurrency()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may paste the text `'US $'` for each numeric column.

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)


Test<-Test%>%mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE))
Test <- Test %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~paste0('US $', .)))

z<-datatable (Test, options = list(columnDefs = 
          list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
            paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,
          dom = 'tip',scrollx=T),rownames = FALSE)
z
```

[image]